# Higher form fermionic conserved currents

Tags: gauge-theory, fermions, noethers-theorem

Higher form conserved currents have already been defined, such as those seen in [Klebanov and Polyakov's work in 2002](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0210114). There, the authors studied the $\text{AdS}_4$/CFT correspondence -- more specifically the correspondence between an O(N) vector theory and the bulk $\text{AdS}_4$ theory.

Here, the $s$-form conserved current is written as
\begin{equation}
J_{(\mu_1\cdots\mu_s)}=\phi^a\partial_\left(\mu_1\right.\cdots\partial_{\left.\mu_s\right)}\phi^a+\cdots,
\end{equation}
where $a=1,2,\cdots,N$ and $\phi^a$ are real scalars.

How would this change if the scalar fields $\phi$ were replaced by Dirac spinors $\psi$ instead?